# How Can i directly redirect products landing page from sales order page

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, redirect, order-grid, landing-pages

I need to directly redirect products landing  page from order page,

[image]

Comment: anchor on item name?

Comment: sorry, what you try to tell me ???

Comment: you want to show link of product landing page?

Comment: if i click products name or sku, redirect to desired products landing page,

Comment: you want to show link of product landing page?     yes

Comment: feel free to raise new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51980/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-gopal-patel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml`

Put Below code

```
    <?php $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $this->getSku());?>
    <h5 class="title"><span id="order_item_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>_title"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></span></h5>
    <div><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><strong><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('SKU') ?>:</strong> <?php echo implode('<br />', Mage::helper('catalog')->splitSku($this->escapeHtml($this->getSku()))); ?></a></div>
```

After

```
<?php if ($_item = $this->getItem()): ?>
```

Comment: @ Gopal Patel: After tried what you suggested above, if products delete, the deleted products supposed in the order, the overall odor not displayed.